# Blinking issue of span with div hover

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

I want to show a span (or a div) when the mouse hovers over a div #choisir-ses-capsules.

```
<div id="choisir-ses-capsules">Deliver with <a id="capsule_1">cap 1</a>,<a id="capsule_2">cap 2</a> et <a id="capsule_3">cap 3</a> <span id="personnaliser" style="display: none;">Change</span>
```

```
$('#choisir-ses-capsules').mouseover(function (e) {
    $("#personnaliser").fadeIn();
});

$('#choisir-ses-capsules').mouseout(function (e) {
    $("#personnaliser").fadeOut();
});
```

The issue is that when the mouse is over a span, the span personnaliser blinks. You can see it here : https://jsfiddle.net/567steh1/2/

Any solution to fix this and stop the span blinking ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the mouseover of the `a` elements within the `#choisir-ses-capsules`. This causes the `mouseout` and `mouseover` to fire repeatedly on the parent. To fix this call `stop(true)` before calling the next `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()`.

```
$('#choisir-ses-capsules').on({
    mouseover: function(e) {
       $("#personnaliser").stop(true).fadeIn();
    }, 
    mouseout: function(e) {
        $("#personnaliser").stop(true).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

That being said, you can both avoid the problem and improve performance by doing this in CSS alone:

```css
#personnaliser {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
#choisir-ses-capsules:hover #personnaliser {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="choisir-ses-capsules">
    Deliver with <a id="capsule_1">cap 1</a>, <a id="capsule_2">cap 2</a> et <a id="capsule_3">cap 3</a> 
    <span id="personnaliser">Change</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented the css solution and it works great !

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the animation - you can use jQuery [stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$('#choisir-ses-capsules').mouseover(function (e) {
    $("#personnaliser").stop().fadeIn();
});

$('#choisir-ses-capsules').mouseout(function (e) {
    $("#personnaliser").stop().fadeOut();
});
```